# Importing a file with the same name as the file you're in

Tags: python, import, names

Lets say you're in a file called logging.py.  If you try to import the standard logging module, you'll end up importing the file you're in.  How can you import the standard logging module from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from samy.vilar gives lots of useful options. But if you're looking for the simplest and most direct answer:

```
import imp
import sys

f, pathname, desc = imp.find_module('logging', sys.path[1:])
logging = imp.load_module('logging', f, pathname, desc)
```

A few things to note here:

The `load_module` call is more like `reload(logging)` than `import logging` in that it won't bind the name `logging` in the local scope, but will replace any existing module under the name `logging`. So, if you've done an `import logging` before this, that name now refers to the new module, not the old one; if you hadn't, the name `logging` isn't bound in your scope. (That's why the `logging =` is there above, to put it into scope.)

I don't know if it's actually guaranteed that the '' that puts the current directory into the module path is actually the first entry in `sys.path`. For that matter, it's always possible to insert '', or for that matter '.', into sys.path yourself. So, if you want to be paranoid you could do something like this:

```
f, pathname, desc = imp.find_module('logging', [path for path in sys.path if path and path[0] != '.'])
```

Or you could get even more paranoid, e.g., compare `abspath(path)` to `sys.argv[0]` and `os.getcwd()` in various ways to make sure nobody is sneakily forcing you to re-import yourself. It depends on what your goals are.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  This is a lot more complicated than I was hoping for though.  I was hoping I could just from __future__ import absolute_import or something.

Answer (score 2):

You could always remove the current directory from `sys.path`, but that's very hackish, and not reliable. After testing, I realized that this can works if the file is being run (as `__main__`, but not if it's being imported, which is very unreliable).

I think the best thing you could do is not name your file with a name that is used by a std lib package.

Comment: The current file's directory is always on the path.  It doesn't matter how deeply nested it is in a package.  It will always be able to import itself (and fail, of course)

Comment: @NickRetallack You're indeed right, I answered a bit too fast without checking! i'll remove that bit then!

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `imp` to load the module with an absolute path.

```
import imp
help(imp.load_module)
load_module(...)
    load_module(name, file, filename, (suffix, mode, type)) -> module
    Load a module, given information returned by find_module().
    The module name must include the full package name, if any.
```

on my mac I did this:

```
import imp
py_logging = imp.load_module('logging', None, '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging', ('', '', 5))
dir(py_logging)
['BASIC_FORMAT', 'BufferingFormatter', 'CRITICAL', 'DEBUG', 'ERROR', 'FATAL', 'FileHandler', 'Filter', 'Filterer', 'Formatter', 'Handler', 'INFO', 'LogRecord', 'Logger', 'LoggerAdapter', 'Manager', 'NOTSET', 'PlaceHolder', 'RootLogger', 'StreamHandler', 'WARN', 'WARNING', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__status__', '__version__', '_acquireLock', '_defaultFormatter', '_handlerList', '_handlers', '_levelNames', '_lock', '_loggerClass', '_releaseLock', '_srcfile', '_startTime', 'addLevelName', 'atexit', 'basicConfig', 'cStringIO', 'codecs', 'critical', 'currentframe', 'debug', 'disable', 'error', 'exception', 'fatal', 'getLevelName', 'getLogger', 'getLoggerClass', 'info', 'log', 'logProcesses', 'logThreads', 'makeLogRecord', 'os', 'raiseExceptions', 'root', 'setLoggerClass', 'shutdown', 'string', 'sys', 'thread', 'threading', 'time', 'traceback', 'types', 'warn', 'warning']

dir(logging)
['BASIC_FORMAT', 'BufferingFormatter', 'CRITICAL', 'DEBUG', 'ERROR', 'FATAL', 'FileHandler', 'Filter', 'Filterer', 'Formatter', 'Handler', 'INFO', 'LogRecord', 'Logger', 'LoggerAdapter', 'Manager', 'NOTSET', 'PlaceHolder', 'RootLogger', 'StreamHandler', 'WARN', 'WARNING', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__status__', '__version__', '_acquireLock', '_defaultFormatter', '_handlerList', '_handlers', '_levelNames', '_lock', '_loggerClass', '_releaseLock', '_srcfile', '_startTime', 'addLevelName', 'atexit', 'basicConfig', 'cStringIO', 'codecs', 'critical', 'currentframe', 'debug', 'disable', 'error', 'exception', 'fatal', 'getLevelName', 'getLogger', 'getLoggerClass', 'info', 'log', 'logProcesses', 'logThreads', 'makeLogRecord', 'os', 'raiseExceptions', 'root', 'setLoggerClass', 'shutdown', 'string', 'sys', 'thread', 'threading', 'time', 'traceback', 'types', 'warn', 'warning']
```

as we can see we have the same the set of components.

keep in mind that this isn't very dry, meaning you would need to update the location of the logging module based on the underlying system you are in, you can check for it by

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.pyc'
```

or use `imp.find_module` `fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('logging')` in a directory where your custom `logging.py` can't be found ...

As a last note Im sure you have your reasons for naming your module `logging.py` I would still recommend something else that wouldn't conflict.

Comment: If you really want to do this, instead of specifying the absolute path, you could iterate `for path in sys.path: if path:` (to skip the '' at the start) and try/catch `imp.load_module(…, os.path.join(path, 'logging.py')` until one succeeds.

Comment: interesting point, still `logging` is a module made up of several files so it would be `dir = os.path.join(path, 'logging')` and it would be a bit dangerous since we don't know if there are any other collisions within our path ...

Comment: OK, yeah, you're right about `logging` rather than `logging.py`. But as for "a bit dangerous"… well, what the OP wants to do is either inherently dangerous, or ambiguous. There really is no definition of "the standard modules", so "the modules on sys.path, except the local path" is about as reasonable as you're going to get. But see my answer below if you want to get paranoid.

Answer (score -1):

Imported files are cached in `sys.modules`, and any attempt to import another module with the same name will simply return the cached module. There's no way to resolve the conflict.

As a hack you could delete the dictionary entry in `sys.modules`, but I don't know how well that would work. Caveat Emptor.

```
del sys.modules['logging']
```

Of course after that you'll have to find a way to modify the path so that the proper file gets imported.

My overall advice is to prevent the situation altogether and rename your file so that there's no conflict.